# RESTful service call with fully qualified URL

Tags: rest, service

I have one application with URL - *http://localhost:9080/Quote*

From this application, I need to make a REST call to *http://localTest:9090/resource/{param1}?key={value}*

Is it possible ?

SO far, whenever I have created REST call - it's within same context root like making call from *http//:localhost:9080/Quote to http://localhost:9080/Quote/resource/{param1}?key={value}*

Comment: Why not trying it out ? Anyway, CORS is the keyword here.

Comment: I did try but @PATH does not accept the fully qualified url..as u can see the domain changes here